# Media player seekTo(position) not working properly

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, seekbar

I am trying to play the song from local storage using `MediaPlayer`. playing song is working properly, but when i am trying to change `mediaPlayer.seekTo(p)` with seekBar `onProgressChanged` listener it always restart the song instead of starting from seeked position. This is not duplicate question i have searched for the solution but nothing works for me.

**Code To Play Song:**

```
    public void playSong(String path) {

    try {

        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getContext(), Uri.parse(path));

        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onPrepared: ");
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

**Change SeekBar Position Listener:**

```
public void circularSeekBarChangeListener(CircularSeekBar circularSeekBar) {

    circularSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new CircularSeekBar.OnCircularSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(CircularSeekBar circularSeekBar, float progress, boolean fromUser) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onProgressChanged: P2 " + progress);

            if (fromUser) {
                int p = (int) progress;
                Log.d(TAG, "onProgressChanged: "+mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(p);
                Log.d(TAG, "onProgress1111  "+mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(CircularSeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(CircularSeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you get any solution?

Comment: I am getting the same issue, but with video - did you get a solution?